# Hilly sequences of length 7

Tags: combinatorics

To start, we try to make the 2nd, 4th, and 6th terms as small as possible. I know that we can use some sort of recursion to go on with this problem, but don’t know how.

Comment: What have you tried? What approaches are you expected to know/use? You've asked a lot of combinatorics questions without showing any sign that you understand (or appreciate) the answers given.

Comment: Yep I figured it out and accepted a lot of the most helpful ones.

Comment: Thanks for explaining to me how this website works Calvin

Comment: @CalvinLin Also, does everyone get a notification if there is a reply, or is it best to @ someone

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know for certain. I _think_ that the poster (or the question or answer) will get notified, but others will only be if you @ them (and you can only @ 1 person at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Recurrence relation.
One of the 2nd, 4th, or 6th term must be 7. Split into 2 parts accordingly.